# What is the default culture of an MSBuild task?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am using MSBuild property functions to convert strings into date time objects or numbers (e.g. `$([System.DateTime]::Parse(2010/01/01))`).

Apparently it is not possible to specify the invariant culture, as `$([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)` is not enabled for execution by default.

That makes me wonder which culture is MSBuild actually using to run string conversions by default?

It makes sense for software to use the invariant culture to make builds reproducible across systems. If this is not the default, I may need to go the extra mile and change it by enabling all property functions for all projects... but before I do that I would like to know whether MSBuild might already be using a reproducible culture as a default. Strangely, I could not find mention of this anywhere in the documentation.